# Compress 2d graphics written image size in java

Tags: java, image

I have an image and using `java.awt.Graphics2D` in java I have written a text on the image. Everything works fine until here. When I tried to compress this image in java using `ImageWriteParam` in java the picture gets overblown. Below is the code which I used to compress the image size. This code works fine for normal images though.

```
    File input = new File("Input Image File");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);

    File compressedImageFile = new File("Compressed image file location");
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);

    Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
    ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();

    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setCompressionQuality(1.0f);  // Change the quality value you prefer
    try {
        writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
        System.out.println(writer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    os.close();
    ios.close();
    writer.dispose();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you use the default `ImageWriterParams`, using `writer.getDefaultWriteParam()`. But as mentioned in the [API of the `ImageWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#getDefaultWriteParam()) it says here:

> [...] The default implementation constructs and returns a new ImageWriteParam object **that does not allow tiling, progressive encoding, or compression**...

there is also a hint on how to handle that issue,

> individual plug-ins **may return an instance of ImageWriteParam with additional optional features enabled**, or they may return an instance of a plug-in specific subclass of ImageWriteParam.